# xmlhttp status 200 message when adding DOCTYPE to page

Tags: javascript, xml, doctype, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code placed into a function and when the function is called it loads my XML file and displays it in a message box:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

     } else
     {
     alert('Panel not communicating.Reason: '+xmlhttp.status);
     }
   }

xmlhttp.open("POST","myfile.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The above code does everything like it's meant to.

However, as soon as I add the following code to the top the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

when I load my function it comes up with the following message:

```
Panel not communicating.Reason: 200
```

however it still loads my XML file like how I want it to.

After searching around it says that xmlhttp status 200 means "OK"

Does anyone know why it's displaying this message?

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that `xmlhttp.readyState` is transitioning to a state other than 4 ("complete") -- this can occur if the whole page doesn't download instantly, which is likely. Your function should probably return immediately when `xmlhttp.readyState != 4`, rather than treating that as an error condition.

You should also strongly consider using a Javascript framework such as jQuery here, as it will save you a lot of unnecessary effort. For instance, all of the code you've got here can be reduced to:

```
$.post("myfile.xml", function(data) {
    alert(data);
}).error(function() {
    alert("Panel not communicating.");
});
```

Comment: I can't use jQuery. I was using it but my device was too slow to load the jQuery js file so I removed it and now its loading fast but now I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you added is not supposed to appear in XML, it was for HTML, so the browser may fail to parse the file, which made the `xmlhttp.readyState==2`, I am not sure for this value, may you check it.